# Guard livereload for non-rails

Tags: lamp, guard, livereload

I currently have a PHP/MySQL based site that I would like to use [Guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) for. However, all indicators in the [README](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload/blob/master/README.md) seems to say that it is only reserved for Rails (or more specifically Rack) based sites. Is this true? Is there a way I can start using Guard-livereload in this LAMP based site?

PS I have used [Guard-Livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) before. My problem is that I can't add it to a Gem file to run bundle install as the documentation says for the PHP/MySQL site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to need a Gemfile in a php-based app. All that the livereload plugin needs is a

`guard 'livereload' do ... end`

block inside a Guardfile.

I've written up a short [tutorial](http://vesselinv.com/livereload-fuelphp/) on how to use in a FuelPHP app. For any other php framework, all that's going to change are the watch directives.

I haven't tested it with apache, nor nginx - only with php's buil-in server - but I don't think there should be a problem for the Livereload Chrome extension to connect as long as the guard server is running.

Comment: livereload in Chrome connects directly to the guard server, so there shouldn't be any issues regardless of nginx/apache/etc.